# Prof. Folland's Advanced Calculus about convergent and Cauchy

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

> In Prof. Folland textbook Adavanced Calculus

$\textbf{1.20 Theorem}$. *A sequence $\{x_k\}$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is convergent if and only if it is Cauchy.*

In this theorem, if discussing $\mathbb{R}^n$, since it is complete, so convergent is Cauchy and vice versa.  However, usually we cannot say a sequence being Cauchy is convergent.

For example, $R(0,1]$ is not a complete space?
When I read this book, I am confused about this.

Ex:$\{\frac{1}{k}\},\ \ k\in N^{++}$, the $\text{inf}\{\frac{1}{k}\} = 0 \notin R(0,1]$

It seems that this textbook does not emphasize this. 
When I read this textbook, I am confused about this.

Comment: There are many misplaced question marks in your question? Do you know how to use a question mark.

Comment: Not quite know this. I'll try to fix some of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many metric spaces in which Cauchy sequences do not converge. In particular, subsets of $\mathbb R$ which are not closed are not complete, so there exist Cauchy sequences in that subset which do not converge.

I like to think that nonconvergent Cauchy sequences are sequences which ought to converge, but cannot because there is a missing point.

Comment: So like $a_n = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$, which is a sequence of rational but the limit is $e$, being a missing point?

Comment: Exactly. THis sequence shows that the rationals are not complete.

Comment: So in the example in my original article, can we say $R(0,1]$ is complete? $0$, which is a infimum of $\{\frac{1}{k}\}$ but not in $R(0,1]$

Comment: If $R(0,1]$ means $(0,1] \subset \Bbb{R}$ then it is not. Because a complete metric space, (thinking $(0,1]$ as a metric subspace of $\Bbb{R}$) is closed, and $(0,1]$ is not.

Comment: Yes, $(0,1]$ is "missing" a point at at the lower end.